# Handling bad entropy in encryption

Tags: python, cryptography, aes, rsa, entropy

I noticed the other day that generating keys with GPG on a server takes forever which suggests bad entropy? This server is combining RSA and AES encryption with quite large RSA keys (generated elsewhere).

The AES key I RSA encrypt (and that is used to encrypt the actual message) are generated with calls to `Crypto.Random.new().read()`. If the entropy is bad on this server isn't there a risk for compromised encryption? Or is a 32 byte AES and a large RSA key "good enough"? (whatever that means)

I'm using the Crypto python module but can switch to cryptography or GnuPG if that effort improves security. Changing server is also an option.

Is SSL affected by bad entropy?

`os.urandom()` vs `Crypto.Random`?

Comment: This is missing any vital information such as the RSA key sizes used, how they are used, timing information, operating system etc.

Comment: The question is not about generating rsa keys with "gpg --gen-key" but I noticed that it took about 20 minutes to generate a key with that command hence I suspected an entropy problem. So the question is wheter bad entropy can affect security on this server during these circumstances and what I can do to improve security.

Comment: Could well be, but you haven't answered any of the questions above, and I removed the one about key gen immediately because you stated that already.

Comment: Assuming you mean pycryptodome/pycrypto for `Crypto`, then `os.urandom(16)` is the same as `Crypo.Random.new().read(16)`, for `Crypto.Random` uses `urandom` inside the code: https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that your server has "bad entropy" or insufficient amounts of entropy; especially if your machine is running any other tasks, or has any human input (such as keypresses or mouse movement), even the 'blocking' entropy should be more than sufficient, unless you're asking for extraordinary amounts of random bits.

I'd check a few other common bottlenecks, including the ping-time to the server, if you have C bindings installed and configured for your python libraries, etc. (In particular, pure python implementations of crypto are notoriously slow.)

Comment: "It's unlikely that your server has "bad entropy" or insufficient amounts of entropy" really? I've had my computer block many times because of this. At the very minimum this answer pre-supposes that entropy is not a problem while it very well could be (while the question does the exact opposite, pre-supposing that it does).